# ftp_get(): Opening BINARY mode data connection when downloading a large file

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to download two files from two different FTP servers. One file is 10 MB in size while the other is 3.3GB in size. The 10MB file is downloaded every time without a problem. The 3.3GB file always encounters an error:

> Code Error: [2] ftp_get(): Opening BINARY mode data connection for
>   bigfile.gz (3232089332 bytes).
> Error/Warning on line 55 in file
>   script.php
> Please go over the collector code.

The size of the file is exactly 3232089332, so this issue appears after the file has finished downloading completely.

Both files are .gz files (so I know they are binary).

There is enough space on the hard drive (currently free 47GB).

It is worthwhile to note that I am able to download the file without any issues using Filezilla.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

The code is as follows:

```
function ftpDownload($server, $username, $password, $filename) {

    if (strpos($server, '://') !== false) $server = substr($server, strpos($server, '://') + 3);

    # set up basic connection

    echo "Connecting to $server\n";
    $connectionId = ftp_connect($server);

    if (!$connectionId) {
        return ['success' => false, 'error' => "FTP Connection has Failed"];
    }

    # login with username and password

    echo "Logging in\n";

    $loginResult = ftp_login($connectionId, $username, $password); 
    ftp_pasv($connectionId, true);

    # check connection

    if (!$loginResult) { 
        return ['success' => false, 'error' => "Failed to login"];
    }

    # Verify the file exists 

    echo "Locating $filename\n";
    $result = ftp_size($connectionId, $filename);

    if ($result == -1) {
        return ['success' => false, 'error' => "Unable to locate $filename in server", 'filename' => false];
    }

    echo "File size ".number_format(($result / 1024 / 1024))." MBs\n";

    # Download the file

    echo "Downloading $filename, this may take a while\n";
    if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/files/'.$filename)) unlink(__DIR__.'/files/'.$filename);
    ftp_pasv($connectionId, true);
    $success = ftp_get($connectionId, __DIR__.'/files/'.$filename, $filename, FTP_BINARY);
    ftp_close($connectionId);

    if ($success == false) {
        return ['success' => false, 'error' => "Failed to download file $filename from server, received error from FTP"];
    }

    if (!file_exists(__DIR__.'/files/'.$filename)) {
        return ['success' => false, 'error' => "Unable to locate $filename in server, filename was not properly stored locally"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is a timeout? Does it always download exactly the same number of bytes or more-or-less the same number of bytes, or is it variable?

Comment: It always downloads the same number of bytes. It is most likely some kind of timeout. Adding ftp_set_option($connectionId, FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 320); caused it to succeed twice, but timeout again the third time. The problem is that while it is better - it is still not that reliable. Is there some way not to wait for the server to respond after the download? Or is the solution just in adding a ridiculously large number of seconds to wait?

Answer (score 0):

Reached a solution. As the timeout occurred after the file has been fully downloaded, instead of using ftp_get() I used the following:

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
@$success = ftp_fget($connectionId, $fp, $filename, FTP_BINARY);
```

Then to verify check whether the transfer was successful, I just compared the downloaded file's filesize using filesize() with the remote file's filesize which I've obtained beforehand (can be seen in the question's code).